# Change volume for installation files in windows

Tags: windows, installation

Is it possible (and if so how) to change volume where windows installers puts their temp install files - eg. during automatic updates or when running installers ?

It allways chooses my mapped remote webdav repository (mapped via diect net drive) and fails. So I have to unmap it manually before any installation :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Right-click on This PC and choose Properties -> Advanced system settings.  On the Advanced tab, click Environment Variables.  Change Temp and TMP to new values.

Answer (score 1):

Use folder redirection with appropriate permissions.

http://m.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/terminal-services/performance/configure-folder-redirection.html

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know what exactly I should do. Which folder should I redirect ? Is some name of the folder where windows installer unpacks msi files ?